# Use an ObjectDataSource in a SharePoint 2013 project

Tags: assembly-references

I'm trying to use an ObjectDataSource in a SharePoint 2013 custom solution but I've the following errors...

Just start with the initial version of the ObjectDataSource:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods" runat="server" TypeName="BLProject.MyClass" />
```

MyNamespace.MyClass comes from another class library that interacts with the database using EntityFramework.

So with this ObjectDataSource I get the error

```
The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'ods' could not be found.
```

Using Google I found this [link](http://bouncetadiss.blogspot.it/2012/03/using-objectdatasource-in-sharepoint.html) so my control has become:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods" runat="server" TypeName="BLProject.MyClass, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
```

But nothing changed, so after another search with Google I added this

```
        <add assembly="BLProject.MyClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

And I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'BLProject.MyClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/704879/The-type-specified-in-the-TypeName-property-of-Obj, i am not developer but i know little bit, you need to have dll deployed and entry added into web.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your class project it will generate a dll in `bin` folder. You need to get the dll and add it to package in your Sharepoint project then deploy or build

Comment: Hello, I followed your suggestion adding the BL dll as both mode (Assembly from Project Output and Existing Assembly) nothing changed. I also added in the same way the EntityFramework.dll.

Comment: Hello, I got the solution and your suggestion was part of it. Thank you!

Comment: i am glad it helped you can mark it up or as your answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in two steps.

The first step is follow the Akshay suggestion ad after I added the assembly reference in the web.config.

Something like

```
<add assembly="BLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicTokenKey=123456" />
```

You can obtain the PublicTokenKey using the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt and the command
    sn -T MyAssembly.dll
from the dll folder.

Thank you again